# Aggregate Function in R using Multiple Criteria

Tags: r, aggregate, criteria

I've been playing around with this formula for a while as I am trying to obtain the number of goals each football team has scored in my dataset. I am able to find out how many goals they have scored at home or away. But I'm struggling to do both combined.

Here's an example of the code I've done. I can add up the goals scored in the FTHG (Full-Time Home Goals) column, but at the moment it is based only on home team goals.

```
goalsScored <- aggregate(FTHG ~ HomeTeam, matchData, sum)
```

I know I've got to add the away goals as well, but I need it so it only counts the goals that specific team scores away. Here it is adding the home and away goals for every match the home team plays, rather than the amount that corresponds to whether they played at home or away.

```
goalsScored <- aggregate(FTHG + FTAG ~ HomeTeam, matchData, sum)
```

Here is an example table (matchData):

```
---------------------------------
HomeTeam | AwayTeam | FTHG | FTAG
TeamA    |  TeamB   |   3  |  1
TeamC    |  TeamD   |   1  |  0
TeamB    |  TeamA   |   2  |  2
TeamD    |  TeamC   |   0  |  3
```

The output should be like this (goalsScored):

```
---------------------------------
Team  | GoalsScored
TeamA |      5
TeamB |      3
TeamC |      4
TeamD |      0
```

Comment: Can you share a small sample of your dataset and also the desired output

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(matchData)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(matchData, 20))`.

Comment: For further clarity, I have just added an example table along with what the output should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your example:

```
df<-data.frame(HomeTeam = c("TeamA","TeamC","TeamB","TeamD"),
               AwayTeam = c("TeamB","TeamD","TeamA","TeamC"),
               FTHG = c(3,1,2,0),
               FTAG = c(1,0,2,3))
```

You can do this with Base R, but `dplyr` makes it easier to do it in steps. Indexing each `team` column and then binding them by rows using `rbind` will allow you to sum them up. You can save it as a separate dataframe if needed.

Here's your output:

```
library(dplyr)

rbind(data.frame(Team = df[,1], Goals_Scored = df[,3]),
      data.frame(Team = df[,2], Goals_Scored = df[,4])) %>%
  group_by(Team) %>% 
  summarize(Goals_Scored = sum(Goals_Scored))

Team  | Goals Scored
TeamA |      5
TeamB |      3
TeamC |      4
TeamD |      0
```

Comment: Thanks, but the example I gave wasn't fully representative of what I'm working with. I have 6,480 entries, so I need a method that can automatically detect a team's home and away games and sum the goals scored. Sorry I didn't mention that.

Comment: This should do that no matter the size of the dataframe. You're indexing the entire column of HomeTeam and the entire column of AwayTeam, and then grabbing their goals scored whether they are home or away. Once you do that, you're appending the away DF to the home DF, grouping by the team, and then summing total goals (home and away) for that team specifically.

Comment: If you try the above and it doesn't work for your example, can you give a bit more data that would show why it doesn't work?